# Index assignment to tensor objects

Tags: python, tensorflow, indexing

I have four tensor objects, e.g., A, B, C, and D (see below).

```
A: <tf.Tensor 'mul_388:0' shape=(5,) dtype=float32>
B: <tf.Tensor 'mul_396:0' shape=(5,) dtype=float32>
C: <tf.Tensor 'clip_by_value_30:0' shape=(5,) dtype=float32>
D: <tf.Tensor 'clip_by_value_31:0' shape=(5,) dtype=float32>
```

I have to create new tensor object E based on the conditions given below:

```
E = C when A <= B
else
E = D
```

What is the best way to do it? I am using Tensorflow version 2.9.1.

I tried following but didn't work.

```
E = C[A <= B]
E = D[A > B]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [tf.cond](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond):

```
E = tf.cond(A <= B, true_fn=lambda: C, false_fn=lambda: D)
```

Comment: Can also do `E = tf.where(A <= B, C, D)`

Comment: For me, `E = tf.where(A <= B, C, D)` worked fine.